# How to access a preview of a hidden language?

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

I have created a language in the sites module whose content is not yet finished. I want this language version to be accessible so that the people involved who know the link can already access it, but for now I don't want it to get an `<link rel="alternate" hreflang="lang_code" href="url_of_page"/>` entry. If I deactivate "Visible in Frontend", it unfortunately cannot be accessed at all:

> Page Not Found
>   The page did not exist or was inaccessible. Reason: Page is not available in the requested language.

As a workaround I have tried to disable the complete hreflang-tag generation, but it does not work either.
See Issue [on Forge](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/91353).

How can I access the page without other languages getting a link (rel alternate) to this version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only backend-editors can access hidden/disabled content.
therefore you might need the adminpanel where you can select options to display hidden content or select another simulated display time to show timed content.

without any BE login you only can access regular visible content, which might have no menu entry.

Comment: The content isn't disabled, only the language via site module. At least the view module should display it, but it does not. With TYPO3 9.5 it was possible to deactivate a language and still access it in FE. The result was that the language was then hidden in language menus and the hreflang and thus not directly visible to search engines. In 10.4 it is no longer accessible at all. The people who need access are non admins and some don't even have a backend access. Enabling the language and disabling the generation of hreflang tags could be a solution, but even that doesn’t work with 10.4.

Comment: there is not so much differnce between pages and languages: if they are hidden, also dependent records are not visible. without a BE-login nothing is visible (as it would implement a security hole). with a BE-login look into admin-panel and the available options to show hidden/unavailable data

Comment: Thank you very much! I've now noticed that the languages in my 9.5 comparison project run via folders (/en/) instead of subdomains, as I set up in the 10.4 project. Thanks to your suggestion with the AdminPanel, I found out that the frontend of the hidden language is accessible when I'm logged into the backend under the same domain - even without the AdminPanel. Then decision makers have to get a BE-access for the preview, I can live with that.